# Implement XOR Operation In Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, xor

Can Somebody explain to me, how i cant use xor operation in elastic search.

I use most keyword for AND, Should keyword for OR, and Not for Not operation, but my mind really stuck when i wanted to implement XOR feature.

I Search a lot and could not get any usefull data.

Help Me, TnQ <3

Comment: Maybe you can implement `A ^ B` as `(A && !B) || (!A && B)`, or `(A || B) && (!A || !B)`.

Comment: @EricLavault I donw know hwo to transfer the formula to elastic query with must, should and must not operator

Comment: XOR can be rewritten as `(A OR B) AND NOT (A AND B)`